# Iframe not loading properly in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, puppeteer

I am trying to parse a website using puppeteer, everything works well but iframe does not load properly.
This is how it loads

[image]

Here is my code

```
    args: [
        "--no-sandbox",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 600 })
  // await waitForFrame(page);
  await page.goto(url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 0,
  });
await page.evaluate(({ applicationUrl}: any ) => {
// Here i want to evaluate iframes
})
```

When i try to log iframes, i don't get the actual iframe link on my parsed website

[image]

Also i don't see the iframe tag in parsed website

[image]

But When i look into the actual page, i can see the iframe link

[image]

and also the iframe tag

[image]

Here is the link to actual page which i am trying to parse
https://leza.notion.site/Trade-log-721b1ebb4cc74175abb55408b6f2d0c3

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's lazy loaded

try scrolling around and then wait some for iframe to load, and then get the iframe:

```
await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    timeout: 0,
});


await page.evaluate(async() => {

    const scroll = document.querySelector('.notion-scroller');

    scroll.scrollBy(0, 900);

    document.querySelector('.notion-video-block').scrollIntoView();

});


// wait some for iframe to load..
await page.waitFor(5000);


const iframeSelector = 'iframe';

const frameHandle = await page.$(iframeSelector);

const src = await page.evaluate(el => el.src, frameHandle);
console.log(src);
```